# Cannot run Dota 2 because of old OpenGL version

Tags: opengl

```
Computer Information:
    Manufacturer:  Unknown
    Model:  Unknown
    Form Factor: Laptop
    No Touch Input Detected

Processor Information:
    CPU Vendor:  GenuineIntel
    CPU Brand:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 370  @ 2.40GHz
    CPU Family:  0x6
    CPU Model:  0x25
    CPU Stepping:  0x5
    CPU Type:  0x0
    Speed:  2399 Mhz
    4 logical processors
    2 physical processors
    HyperThreading:  Supported
    FCMOV:  Supported
    SSE2:  Supported
    SSE3:  Supported
    SSSE3:  Supported
    SSE4a:  Unsupported
    SSE41:  Supported
    SSE42:  Supported
    AES:  Unsupported
    AVX:  Unsupported
    CMPXCHG16B:  Supported
    LAHF/SAHF:  Supported
    PrefetchW:  Unsupported

Operating System Version:
    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (64 bit)
    Kernel Name:  Linux
    Kernel Version:  4.10.0-42-generic
    X Server Vendor:  The X.Org Foundation
    X Server Release:  11903000
    X Window Manager:  Compiz
    Steam Runtime Version:  steam-runtime-beta-release_2017-10-05

Video Card:
    Driver:  Intel Open Source Technology Center Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
    Driver Version:  2.1 Mesa 17.4.0-devel
    OpenGL Version: 2.1
    Desktop Color Depth: 24 bits per pixel
    Monitor Refresh Rate: 59 Hz
    VendorID:  0x8086
    DeviceID:  0x46
    Revision Not Detected
    Number of Monitors:  1
    Number of Logical Video Cards:  1
    Primary Display Resolution:  1366 x 768
    Desktop Resolution: 1366 x 768
    Primary Display Size: 13.90" x 7.80" (15.91" diag)
                                            35.3cm x 19.8cm (40.4cm diag)
    Primary VRAM Not Detected

Sound card:
    Audio device: Realtek ALC269VB

Memory:
    RAM:  3746 Mb

Miscellaneous:
    UI Language:  English
    LANG:  en_US.UTF-8
    Total Hard Disk Space Available:  465497 Mb
    Largest Free Hard Disk Block:  288881 Mb
    VR Headset: None detected
```

EDIT : Sorry, I was so frustrated I did not finish my question. The problem I am having is that my system is stuck on OpenGl 2.1. and Dota2 needs 3.1. I was wondering if there is a workaround for that.

FINAL EDIT : Thank you for the response. I will have to upgrade the system. But I got to learn some other things about upgrading drivers and stuff. Thanks

Comment: What is DOTA 2 ?

Comment: @Rinzwind. Sorry, made an edit to question. I am stuck on OpenGL2.1, whereas Dota2 needs 3.1. I read somewhere there is a workaround this, but cant seem to figure that out. I know I can get a better system and hardware. I just want to see if I can run the game on this system.

Comment: OpenGL: https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers support for 4.5 is in there.

Comment: Voting to Leave Open as @Rinzwind comment answers OP question which has been made more clear.

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind. I have done all that. For some reason, it still is on Driver Version:  2.1 Mesa 17.4.0-devel
    OpenGL Version: 2.1
So, I think I have hit a hardware brick wall.

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#First_generation), Intel's Ironlake HD graphics from 2010 only has OpenGL 2.1 support. You get OpenGL 3.0 with the next generation Sandy Bridge in 2011.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get OpenGL 3.1 with Intel's Ironlake. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Fifth_generation) the hardware only supports OpenGL 2.1. Don't bother with updates of drivers and mesa.

An external graphics card is probably out of the question, given the mobile CPU, `Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU  M 370  @ 2.40GHz`.

In short, you need a new gaming rig.